# Use of helping verb in interrogative sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, interrogatives

Look at these two examples:

**Why did Dolores try to flood the forge?**

**Why Dolores tried to flood the forge?**

Is the second example grammatically wrong as the *helping verb* is not used before the subject in the interrogative sentence? What is the exact rule for constructing this type of *interrogative sentences*?

Answer (score 1):

There is one subject and two verbs! If you want to form an interrogative sentence, a question, you must have a [helping verb](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/Helping-Verbs.html) or an auxiliary one. That said, the first sentence is correct

> Why ***did*** Dolores ***try*** to flood the forge?

The second sentence may not be considered as *interrogative* because it does not have the helping verb though it has another verb *try.*

However, the second sentence can be used in certain context provided it should not be called a question or interrogative sentence. Rather, it would be a normal sentence.

> I don't know *why Dolores tried to flood the forge.*

A must-to-read [reference is here.](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/interrogative-sentence-examples.html)

Answer (score 1):

The second one ("Why Dolores tried...?") is grammatically incorrect.

---

Making questions in English is tricky!  We always use the helping verb "to do" when creating a question, like

> The cat eats fish. 
>   Does the cat eat fish?

**unless** the original verb was *to be*:

> Ellen is tall.
>  
>    Is Ellen tall?

or it was a modal:

> Ray can swim.
>   Can Ray swim?

or the verb was in a perfect tense:

> They have eaten.
>   Have they eaten?

Sometimes in British English *to have* is treated the same way.

> He has a ticket.
>   Has he a ticket? (British)
>   Does he have a ticket? (US)

If we're asking about the subject of a sentence, using *who*, *which*, or *what*, we don't use "to do":

> The captain gave a speech.
>   Who gave a speech?
>
> The fifth president resigned.
>   Which president resigned?
>
> A book fell off the shelf.
>   What fell off the shelf?

---

But for the statement "Dolores tried to flood the forge", the main verb is not *to be*, it's not in the perfect tense, *to try* is not a modal, and we're not asking a who/which/what question about the subject, so it follows the normal rule, and we have to use "to do": "Why *did* Dolores try...?"